# Replicate some data with relations

Tags: laravel

I have a problem i need to replicate the selected survey. When i click on the button he need to replicate all data from that selected survey.

I'm new to Laravel so i dont know how to do this. But i already tried some things but its not working. and i dont know why. Someone can help me out??

Public function controller:

```
public function copySurvey( Manager $fractal, SurveyTransformer $surveyTransformer ) {
    // Copy function (Alleen nog niet volledig hier nog even aanwerken.)
    $copy = Survey::first();

    //copy attributes
    $newsurvey = $copy->replicate();
    $newsurvey->sid = 123456;

    // save it
    $newsurvey->save();
}
```

Model relations survey:

```
public function accuracy() {

    return $this->hasOne( 'App\Models\LimeSurvey\Accuracy', 'survey_id', 'sid' );
}

public function groups() {

    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\LimeSurvey\Group', 'sid', 'sid' )->orderBy('gid', 'asc')->orderBy('group_order', 'asc');
}

public function questions() {

    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\LimeSurvey\Question', 'sid', 'sid' )->orderBy('gid', 'asc')->orderBy('question_order', 'asc');
}

public function parentQuestions() {

    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\LimeSurvey\Question', 'sid', 'sid' )->where('parent_qid', '=', 0)->orderBy('gid', 'asc')->orderBy('question_order', 'asc');
}

public function languages() {

    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\LimeSurvey\Language', 'surveyls_survey_id', 'sid' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate trougth relations after save:

```
$original = Survey::first();

$new = $original->replicate();
$new->sid = 123456;
$new->save();

foreach($original->groups as $group){
    $new->groups()->attach($group);
}

foreach($original->questions as $question){
    $new->questions()->attach($question);
}
```

Comment: Yeah  thankyou! But i uses 2 databases so this method dont work for me say someone. He say i need to use sql code so i can insert it manually. Do you know more about this???